# Alias folder of executables with prepended keyword

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I have several executable files in a folder `/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/`.

Examples are `ruby` `bundler` `chef`.

Ideally I want to be able to run these files by simply prepending the keyword `chef-$1` or `chef $1` where $1 is the executable name. However my `zsh` function doesn't appear to respect the absolute path.

```
function chef(){
  "/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/" $1
}
```

Running

```
➜  ~ chef ruby 
zsh: no such file or directory: ./opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/
```

Functions or aliases - I don't mind either way.

Comment: simple typo with the space? `chef() { /usr/bin/"$1" }` does what I think you want

Comment: is there any reason you haven't just added `/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/` to your `$PATH`?  that would let you run any of the scripts in that directory without a `chef()` function.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you have a space between the path and the `$1`. Try this instead:

```
function chef(){
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/"$1"
}
```

Comment: or `local cmd="$1" ; shift ; "/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/$cmd" "$@"` if args need to be passed to the scripts.